# how to set hyperlink in UILabel Text in iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel which text is **www.google.com**. Now if someone moves the cursor on the text and press it the google's homepage should be open. Is it possible? please explain how.

```
[emptyLabel setText:@"Sorry it looks like google is not currently available in any of your favourite places nearby, why not ask them to sign up at www.google.com"]
```

Comment: why you not using UIButton with Costume type..?

Comment: 1st thing is that user will never move cursor on UILabel. 2nd - if you want no underlining of label, simply attach tap gesture to uilabel and add target.

Comment: @user2750542 you should use UIButton with custom type. and set its title label (which you are giving as label text right now).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`NIAttributedLabel`](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusAttributedLabel.html) from the [Nimbus project](http://nimbuskit.info). This is a drop-in `UILabel` replacement that auto-detects and creates tappable links.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use UITextView and enable data detectors and disable editing which gives a feel of UILabel. UItextview with necessary attributes set will automatically detects http links, phone numbers and so on

If UILabel has to be used, then you need to add a UITapgesture and provide a target for the tap.

Answer (score 1):

```
// While Loading the view

[self underlineLabel:label withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)]; 
[label addGestureRecognizer:gr];
gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

//

- (CGFloat)widthOfString:(NSString *)string withFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:font];
    CGFloat width = stringSize.width;
    return width;
}

- (CGFloat)heightOfString:(NSString *)string withFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:font];
    CGFloat height = stringSize.height;
    return height;
}

-(void)underlineLabel:(UILabel *)lbl withFont:(UIFont *)fnt {
    float wdth = [self widthOfString:lbl.text withFont:fnt];
    float higt = [self heightOfString:lbl.text withFont:fnt];
    UIView *viw = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((lbl.frame.size.width - wdth) / 2, (lbl.frame.size.height / 2) + (higt / 2), wdth, 2)];
    [viw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor bluecolor]];
    [lbl addSubview:viw];
}

// To Add action for gesture recognizer:

- (void)myAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    // Define actions here
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Comment: This answer (create an attributed text label that looks like a link, set User Interaction Enabled, add a TapGestureRecogniser) is *much* more easily executed in Interface Builder than in code, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use UTTextView which automatically detects url or create button separately for the url.
Thanks.